# How can I mock the time for solidity tests?

Tags: solidity, testing, timestamp

My contract has an expiration date that I'd like to unit test but I don't know how to go about doing that. If I could mock the time of the contract that would be dope. Google search provided no information though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general testing method, you can create another, debugging-only, contract descending from your production contract. This second contract can have methods to do anything--for example, to set the expiration date to `now`.

If you want to mess with time specifically, TestRPC has an RPC method to fast forward time. Be warned, you'll have to integrate it into your testing harness somehow, since web3 does not come with it.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing, see http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/chain-forking-exploiting-the-dao

Comment: But there was no way to reset the time back so I made a pr for that feature

Answer (score 5):

This is a fairly old question but I thought I would add this for those looking:

You can utilize the evm_increaseTime method that you get with both hardhat and ganache.

Here's an example with ethers

```
await ethers.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [10]) // add 10 seconds
await ethers.provider.send("evm_mine", []) // force mine the next block
```

And here with web3

```
web3.currentProvider.send({jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "evm_increaseTime", params: [10], id: 0})
web3.currentProvider.send({jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "evm_mine", params: [], id: 0})
```

Comment: Bro you are a life saver!

Answer (score 4):

I've been making my contracts descend from a simple contract that has a `currTime()` function and a `testing` boolean. If I set `testing` to true, `currTime()` returns a fake time, which I can manipulate with functions like `addDays(uint days)`. If `testing` is false, then `currTime()` just returns `block.timestamp`. Every place where I'd check the timestamp, I call `currTime()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is what I needed to get my tests working. One more question though, when you deploy your contract do you remove the contract that you use to manipulate the current time?

Comment: That's tricky. You don't really want to change the tested code when you deploy, but it's kinda nasty leaving it in, too. I guess you just have to decide what's best for your particular contract.

Comment: Good call. I actually just rewrote all my tests to Mocha tests as it's easier to manipulate time that way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library in Dapphub:
https://github.com/dapphub/ds-warp

> A simple mixin for controlling time.
>
> Return the current time with era(). Advance time with warp.
>
> warp(0) to lock the current time to the blocktime.

```
contract DSWarpTest is DSTest {
    DSWarp warp;

    function setUp() {
        warp = new DSWarp();
    }
    function testInit() {
        assertEq(warp.era(), now);
    }
    function testWarp() {
        var tic = now;
        warp.warp(1);
        assertEq(warp.era(), tic + 1);
    }
    function testWarpLock() {
        warp.warp(0);
        assertEq(warp.era(), now);
    }
    function testFailAfterWarpLock() {
        warp.warp(0);
        warp.warp(1);
    }
}
```